# Is there a way to secure PyYAML?

Tags: serialization, thrift, avro, pyyaml

Having this in mind:

http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201302/war_is_peace.html

Is there a way to use `.load` method safely to get class instance and not just dictionary?

Say, like use  `.safe_load`, verify that object is kosher and then use `.load`. Does it entail some risks? Is this doable, safe, practical?

Incidentally, do frameworks such as Thrift or Avro provide working security features? Has someone here worked deep enough in those projects to say if security there has been addressed?